Find text inside top-level brackets when they're nested
I have a file with nested brackets. I need to parse the text within the top-level brackets with Python regex.
import re
string = '{a {b} c} {d}'

# desired output: ['a {b} c', 'd']

# non-greedy
pattern_1 = r'(?<={).*?(?=})' 
print(re.findall(pattern_1, string))
# actual output: ['a {b', 'd']

# greedy
pattern_2 = r'(?<={).*(?=})'
print(re.findall(pattern_2, string))
# actual output: ['a {b} c} {d']

How can I achieve this? With the greedy option it stops too late, with the non-greedy option it stops too soon.

Have you considered not using regex for this?

Here, just replace ( with { and ) with }. See the solution adapted for this scenario. This is a good non-regex solution.
